# What is the significance of Dick Van Dyke playing both Mr Dawes and Bert?

Tags: analysis, mary-poppins

What is the significance of Dick Van Dyke playing both Mr Dawes and Bert in *Mary Poppins*? I have a feeling that [something of this sort](http://www.etonline.com/movies/150432_mary_poppins_hidden_relationships_fan_theory/) might have been intended, but is there any official word on such? Has there been other speculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any behind the scenes *meaning* of why Van Dyke played both roles. Van Dyke had lobbied Walt Disney for the part for some time before Disney acquiesced to allow him to play it. According to [this article from the LA Times](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/culturemonster/2010/01/a-very-familiar-face-returns-to-mary-poppins.html):

> Van Dyke had to cajole Walt Disney into giving him the part because Disney thought Van Dyke -- then in his 30s -- was too young to be the ancient moneyman. The actor reportedly **won him over by acing a screen test, agreeing to portray Dawes for free and making a donation to the California Institute of the Arts, which Disney co-founded**.

NOTE: Emphasis mine.

It seems it was just a matter of Van Dyke wanting the part and being a "go-getter" was able to convince Disney in the end.

Comment: I'd suspect the bribe had more to do with it than the acting :P